# When should I store reference or pointer to functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

I have a vector of std::functions

```
Using Functors = std::vector<std::function<bool(int)>>;
Functors fs;
```

Now if I want to add one function to the vector, I do:

```
fs.emplace_back(
    [](int v)->bool { return v > 1; }
)
```

I am wondering when I declare "Functors", should I make it pointer to std::function instead of raw std::function? It means instead, I will declare like this:

```
    Using Functors = std::vector<
     std::function<bool(int)>*
    >; // note the last &
```

Thus when I call emplace_back, I would just pass in a pointer instead of copy? Or the lambda closure is movable? Please shed some light here: when should I use reference to std::function?

Comment: You can't have a `vector` of references. Use `std::ref` instead of `&`.

Comment: I think std::ref is how you get a reference from a object, not how you define it?

Comment: `std::ref` is a helper that enables you to get a `std::reference_wrapper`

Comment: I'm not sure that you need to edit your question, otherwise my reply doesn't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `std::vector<std::function<bool(int)>>`.

`std::function` when moved is almost always cheap.

For it not to be cheap, the function object stored has to (A) be small, (B) have a no-except move constructor and (C) be expensive to move.

It isn't hard to *write* such an object on purpose, but it is hard to write one *accidentally*.

Now, how small is not mandated by the standard; for MSVC they set it to the size of one or two `std::string`s, as an example.

Almost certainly the overhead of managing raw pointers will make your code worse and less performant than using values here.  Both because you'll be burning mental resources fixing raw pointer bugs, and because allocating objects on the free store is more expensive than what `std::function` does when it moves almost any type by orders of magnitude.

On average, elements in a `std::vector` will be moved a constant number of times (1-3 usually) if you populate the vector from empty with `push_back` due to the mandate that the memory managed grow exponentially, and objects are only moved when a resize is required.

Embrace value semantics.

Comment: So to sum up, Yakk advice is use `std::vector<std::function<bool(int)>>`.

Comment: FYI: the standard does mandate the minimum size of the small object optimization for function in http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func.con#4

Comment: @nevin technicaly it mandates certain types may not fail with an exception; this does not mandate that any other type be supported, nor does it mandate efficiency or even no heap allocation *if* failure is somehow handled.  But in practice, yes, you can expect `sizeof(void*)` to fit in the SOO, and often more.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a reference can't be a parameter type of a template, so you would need to use either a pointer or `std::reference_wrapper` instead:

```
std::vector<std::function<bool(int)>*>
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::function<bool(int)>>>
```

In your example, your vector won't be able to hold "references" to functions because you call `emplace_back` on an r-value. So here, `std::vector<std::function<bool(int)>>` seems a good solution to me.

Comment: Thanks, my question is how efficient it is if I use a copy? Do I have to copy the function object each time I insert a new one?

Comment: Your question didn't mention efficiency but copying functions is very efficient as long as there are no captures in the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** Never!
(At least not when you are talking about `std::function<...>*` - see below)

If you really only want to store functions, make a vector of function pointers:

```
std::vector<bool(*)(int)> fs;
```

This also works for lambdas with an empty capture as in your example, because they implicitly convert to function pointers.

If you want to store arbitrary capable objects, a `std::vector<std::function<bool(int)>>;` should be fine 99.9% of the time. It is simple, you are unlikely to make any errors and the most space efficient solution.

If you really want to create the std:: function objects on the heap for some reason, then use unique_ptr:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr< std::function<bool(int)> >> fs;
fs.push_back( std::make_unique< std::function<bool(int)> >( [](int){ return true;}) );
```

This will make sure you don't forget to delete those objects.

---

**Explanation:**

Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems to me as if you had a missunderstanding about what `std::function` is. It is not a class representing a native function, but a (rather heavy) class that can wrap any callable (functions, function objects, pointer to member functions - even pointer to members).

- Storing function pointers is both very efficient (they are just 4-8 bytes big and trivial to copy/move around) and safe, as the function's address is valid throughout the whole program (ignoring dynamically loading of shared libraries).
- Indirection through a `std::function` adds a significant overhead (they are usually acouple of pointers in size and move/copy are actual functions) but it is still safe.
- Storing a raw pointer to a `std::function` usually requires to create that object on the heap, which comes at additional overhead, but at least moving is cheap again. However it comes with the usualy problems of raw owning pointers. Hence the solution with `std::unique_ptr`.